# Docker: how to run apache service when container starts?

Tags: docker

I don't use any docker file. 
I run my container with:

```
docker run -it --restart always -p 80:80 v1  /bin/bash
```

Then I need to type in

```
service apache2 start
```

How to run the apache service automatically when docker container starts ?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what `v1` is, sorry. But if you check the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/), you will see, that `docker run` has the following format:

> $ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]

`COMMAND` is the command executed on start. The docs even suggest how to run nginx on start automatically:

> `docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image service nginx start`

From all this you may derive, that you need to run something like

```
docker run -it --restart always -p 80:80 v1 service apache2 start
```

Comment: v1 is the name if image.  docker run -it --restart always -p 80:80 v1 script.sh; will that run script.sh that is on docker container ?

Comment: yes, but you have to put your `script.sh` somewhere inside your image. Take a look at [my image here](https://gitlab.com/flexbox/dockerimage-centos-php7/blob/master/Dockerfile), it does `COPY start.sh /tmp/start.sh` and sets `CMD`, which then runs that.

Comment: can I run many commands ? docker run -it --restart always -p 80:80 v1 service apache2 start;service mysql start;